# Hazelcast Jet Continuous Deletion of snapshots

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

After running distributed streams, it looks like whatever these snapshots are not removed from monitoring or something.

These just continue to log every 5 second even though job was finished. Please advise if anything is needed regarding implementation.

Using:

- Hazelcast 3.9.1
- Jet 0.5.1

`2017-12-14 16:26:22,649 [hz.ttcore.cached.thread-8] DEBUG com.hazelcast.jet.impl.SnapshotRepository - [localhost]:18320 [ttcore] [0.5.1] Deleted all snapshots for job 857d-8e5e-0e20-df3b
2017-12-14 16:26:32,651 [hz.ttcore.cached.thread-1] DEBUG com.hazelcast.jet.impl.SnapshotRepository - [localhost]:18320 [ttcore] [0.5.1] Deleted all snapshots for job 857d-8e5e-0e20-df3b
2017-12-14 16:26:37,649 [hz.ttcore.cached.thread-1] DEBUG com.hazelcast.jet.impl.SnapshotRepository - [localhost]:18320 [ttcore] [0.5.1] Deleted all snapshots for job 857d-8e5e-0e20-df3b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a log from a background GC process. It says "all" even in case no snapshots were deleted.

It's on `DEBUG` level, which should normally be disabled unless you are interested in debugging.